# Issue with Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have an Applet in my HTML page as bellow:

```
<object  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
           width = "1" 
           height = "1" 
           name = "LMSTestSCODriver"  
           codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.4/jinstall-14-win32.cab#Version=1,4,0,0"
           alt = "This object contains the LMSTestSCOApplet">
     <param name = "CODE"      value = "org.adl.testsuite.rte.lms.comm.LMSTestSCOApplet.class" />
     <param name = "CODEBASE"  value = "../common" />
     <param name = "ARCHIVE"   value = "LMSTest.jar" />
     <param name = "NAME"      value = "LMSTestSCODriver" />
     <param name = "type"    value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.4" />
     <comment>
        <applet code    = "org.adl.testsuite.rte.lms.comm.LMSTestSCOApplet.class"
                archive = "LMSTest.jar"
                name    = "LMSTestSCODriver"
                id      = "NNLMSTestSCODriver"
                width   = "1"
                height  = "1"
                mayscript = "true">
           <param name = "codebase" value = "../common" />
        </applet>
     </comment>
  </object>
```

The following error occurs:

*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'evalID'*

on the following line:

**var result = LMSTestSCODriver.evalID( query1 + "!" + query2 );**

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: Does the applet have the method evalID?

Comment: Yes, it has the method evalID.

Comment: Could the problem be that you have the same name on both the applet and the object? Try giving the applet a different name and use that instead to access it. Or use NNLMSTestSCODriver.evalID(...

Answer (score 0):

I would change the entire approach used for deploying this applet.  Oracle provides [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) for deploying both applets and JWS apps.